# javafx getResources for fxml always returns null

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, javafx-11

I have a Gradle/JavaFX Project and I am trying to load a fxml via getResources, but it always returns null.
The files get copied to the right folder, when built.
I don't know if there is something wrong with the classpath.
I am trying to run this with IntelliJ Idea.

The Project Structure

[image]

Here is the class where I try to load it:

```java
    public class Main extends Application {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            try {
    
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                final URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/dashboard.fxml");
                loader.setLocation(resource);
                AnchorPane root = loader.load();
    
                primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
                primaryStage.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I also tried `getClass().getResource("/dashboard.fxml")` and `Main.class.getResource("/dashboard.fxml")`.

Here is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
}

group 'swe4'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/resources"]
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

javafx {
    version = "15.0.1"
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}
```

Comment: It seems there is really a problem with the classpath, since the output resource folder is not added to it.

It works when I change the build.gradle tot his "hack".



sourceSets {
    main.output.resourcesDir = main.java.outputDir
}

Comment: Note you don't need the configuration you have in `sourceSets { ... }`. What you're doing there is already done by the [Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#java_plugin) (which, by the way, is implicitly added by the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)). I don't know if getting rid of the `sourceSets { ... }` block will fix your problem, but you should get rid of it anyway.

Comment: Also, your image shows that the resources are copied to the output folder. But you're checking the _wrong_ output folder. The `out` folder is used by IntelliJ. It's the `build` folder that's used by Gradle. Since you should be delegating all build actions (including running your project) to Gradle you need to inspect the `build` folder. The fact you're using IntelliJ directly to run your project may actually be the source of your problem. Try executing `./gradlew run` to see if that works (though first you need to configure the `application` plugin so it knows the main class).

Comment: Thanks, it seems I only have the problem when trying to run this with intellij and not with gradle. Running it with gradle and removing the source set worked.